# Reading multiple urls from text file and processing web page

Tags: python, url

The input to the script is a text file with multiple urls from web pages. The intended steps in the script are as follows:

- read a url from the text file
- strip the url to use it as a name for the output file (fname)
- use the  regex ‘clean_me’ to clean up the content of url/web page.
- write the contents to the file (fname)
- repeat for each file in the input file.

This is the contents of the input file `urloutshort.txt`;

http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/autonews/ColumnistsAndBloggers/~3/6HV2TNAKqGk/diesel-with-no-nox-emissions-it-may-be-possible

http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/entire-site-rss/~3/3j3Hyq2TJt0/kyocera-corp-opens-its-largest-floating-solar-power-plant-in-japan.html

http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/entire-site-rss/~3/KRhGaT-UH_Y/crews-replace-rhode-island-pole-held-together-with-duct-tape.html

This is the script :

```
import os
import sys
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib
import re

def clean_me(htmldoc):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldoc.text.encode('UTF-8'), 'html5lib')
    for s in soup(['script', 'style']):
    s.decompose()       
    return ' '.join(soup.stripped_strings)
with open('urloutshort.txt', 'r') as filein:
    for url in filein:
        page = requests.get(url.strip())
        fname=(url.replace('http://',' '))
        fname = fname.replace ('/',' ')
        print (fname)
        cln = clean_me(page)
        with open (fname +'.txt', 'w') as outfile:              
        outfile.write(cln +"\n")
```

This is the error message;

```
python : Traceback (most recent call last):
At line:1 char:1
+ python webpage_A.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (most recent call last)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  File "webpage_A.py", line 43, in <module>
    with open (fname +'.txt', 'w') as outfile:                              
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ' feedproxy.google.com ~r autonews ColumnistsAndBloggers ~3 6HV2TNAKqGk 
diesel-with-no-nox-emissions-it-may-be-possible\n.txt'
```

The problem appears related to reading the url(s) from the text file because if I bypass the script for reading the input file and just hard code one of the urls then the script will process the web page and save the results to a txt  file with a name extracted from the url.  I have searched the topic on SO, but have not found a solution.

Help with this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the following piece of code :

```
    with open (fname +'.txt', 'w') as outfile:              
    outfile.write(cln +"\n")
```

fname contains "\n" which cannot be a valid file name to open. All you need to do is just change it to this

```
    with open (fname.rstrip() +'.txt', 'w') as outfile:              
    outfile.write(cln +"\n")
```

**Full Code fix included:**

```
import os
import sys
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import html5lib

def clean_me(htmldoc):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldoc.text.encode('UTF-8'), 'html5lib')
    for s in soup(['script', 'style']):
        s.decompose()
        return ' '.join(soup.stripped_strings)


with open('urloutshort.txt', 'r') as filein:
    for url in filein:
        if "http" in url:
            page = requests.get(url.strip())
            fname = (url.replace('http://', ''))
            fname = fname.replace('/', ' ')
            print(fname)
            cln = clean_me(page)
            with open(fname.rstrip() + '.txt', 'w') as outfile:
                outfile.write(cln + "\n")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Made the change to the script as suggested.  The script processes the first url  as intended but not the subsequent urls in urloutshort.txt.  I changed the order of the urls in the file but that did not change the outcome;  the first url gets processed but not the subsequent ones.

Comment: python : Traceback (most recent call last):
At line:1 char:1
+ python webpage.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (most recent call last)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: File "webpage.py", line 33, in <module>
    page = requests.get(url.strip())
  File "C:\Users\rschafish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

Comment: File "C:\Users\rschafish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rschafish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)

Comment: File "C:\Users\rschafish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Users\rschafish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 305, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)

Comment: File "C:\Users\rschafish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 379, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?

Comment: Apologies for the multiple comments but there is a character restriction on each comment so I had to post the error in parts

Comment: Let me check it for you

Comment: i've added the Fix now , please try this code and let me know if it works for you

Comment: Hi toheedNiaz....that last Fix worked perfectly.  As you can see I am using the script to extract text from web sites.  I plan on using NLTK modules to further analyze the extracted text.  thanks again for your help